# ShieldUI Grid - Hide Columns by index?

Tags: shieldui

Is it possible to hide columns by index? The hideColumn() function uses the field NAME:

```
hideColumn(columnField)
```

I guess I'll have to create an array of fieldnames and do it that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the name of the data field in a certain column, specifying its index like this:

```
$("#grid .sui-gridheader th.sui-headercell:eq(0)").attr("data-field")
```

However, you will have to take into account things such as whether it is hidden or not.